# https://github.com/autodesk-platform-services/aps-industrial-construction-explored. mongoDB GOT connected successfully. NOTHING PROGRESSES FROM THEN

Tags: autodesk-forge, construction, industrial

We are keen to have 3D model overlay on Google map and handle the click event so show the graphs viz temperature and pressure realtime data.

Also, the issues reported by the system to be notified to responsible persons.

Above url when cloned and executed locally, got connected to mongoDB successfully. and nothing progresses from then

Also we do not get to see any NEW COLLECTION, DOCUMENTS being added in mongoDB related to 'issues'

[image]
Please guide

Answer (score 1):

The https://github.com/autodesk-platform-services/aps-industrial-construction code sample has a couple more prerequisites if you want to run it yourself, especially when it comes to naming your 3D designs uploaded to APS. I've added more details about them in the [README](https://github.com/autodesk-platform-services/aps-industrial-construction?tab=readme-ov-file#sample-data).